# How can i add icon to options menu item

Tags: android, android-layout, menuitem

I want to add icons to the options menu item , i searched many tutorials but still am not able to display icons in my options menu.

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:icon="@drawable/star"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:id="@+id/option"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
tools:context="com.example.siva.prep.MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/menu_gift"
    android:icon="@drawable/gift"
    android:title="Giftbox"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
    android:icon="@drawable/share"
    android:title="Club/social"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_heart"
    android:icon="@drawable/heart"
    android:title="Im Lucky" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_cart"
    android:icon="@drawable/cart"
    android:title="Shopping cart"
    android:textSize="16dp" /></menu>
```

Comment: I need to fix this , anybody please help me...

Comment: Most likely, you do not have an options menu in the first place. The options menu was a 2008-2011 UI pattern. More likely, you have an overflow menu in the action bar, and in that case, that menu simply does not show icons.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_more"
    android:title="Main Menu"
    app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_add"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="Add"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_remove"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_remove"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="remove"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
    </menu>
</item>
```